# How to make statement case insensitive when uploading a dta file with specified columns?

Tags: for-loop, import, stata, using, case-insensitive

I want to loop through different files:

```
forvalues y=2014/2022 {
    use var1 var2 var3 using "file_`y'.dta"
    save "file2_`y'
}
```

However, some of the files have var names `VAR1 VAR2 var3` instead of `var1 var2 var3`.
How do I make the statement case insensitive?

Comment: `for values` won't work. Please fix it to `forvalues` or `forval` or something else legal.

Comment: If you have inconsistent variable names in different datasets, make them consistent first in a loop over datasets with statements like `capture rename VAR1, lower`. Otherwise with these datasets you will be writing awkward code to cope with the inconsistencies in everything that uses them henceforth.

Comment: @NickCox where would I put that capture code? As the first thing in the loop?

Comment: You need to read in the dataset. Then try your `rename` statements. You can't go `use var1 var2 var3` etc. unless those are the names actually in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a concise way to do this, but here's an example using `describe` and `capture` to first check if the variable is contained in the .dta file.

First make the simple data examples with different cases:

```
tempfile the_data1 the_data2
clear
input var1 VAR2 var3
0 1 0
end 
save `the_data1', replace 

clear
input var1 var2 VAR3 // note uppercase is different from above
0 1 0
end 
save `the_data2', replace
```

Then this loop handles the different names. The outer loop goes through the two files and creates an empty local `myvarlist` which will contain the appropriate variable names for that file. The `capture` line tries a describe command of the lowercase variable. If it works (`_rc==0`), the lowercase name is added to the list. If it fails (`rc!=0`), the uppercase name is added to the list. After looping through the variables, the `use` line works because the cases have all been corrected.

```
forvalues i=1/2 {
    local myvarlist ""
    foreach myvar in var1 var2 var3 {
        capture noisily describe `myvar' using `the_data`i'' 
        if (_rc==0) local myvarlist "`myvarlist' `myvar'"
        if (_rc!=0) local myvarlist = "`myvarlist' " + upper("`myvar'")
    }
    use `myvarlist' using `the_data`i''
    describe 
    * Save file here
}
```

Comment: Helpful (+1) but please see my comment on the question.

Comment: Thanks @NickCox! I agree with your comment in general...I think I could see this as the least bad option if the raw .dta files are quite large and you want code that works on the raw files for reproducibility.

Comment: Good point! That could be crucial in some cultures.